# Jenkins Docker Run and Sh script concurrently

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, containers

Is there a way to run a shell command during docker run without using the docker file?

What I have right now is this, but it seems to start the container and then run the sh script afterwards. What I need to do set up a user during container running time because it runs with super user privilege (correct me if I'm wrong).

```
node('linuxNode') {

    docker.image('docker/repo').inside(
        '--privileged ' + 
        '--volume "...") 
    {
        sh '/home/path/to/script/createNewUser.sh'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue, before I was giving argument in '-v ____ ' + '-v ____ ' + ... form, and for some reason the jenkins docker workflow plugin was scrambling the order of this arguments. So instead I have one single long with the sh command at the end.

That should fix the issue most of the time, but in my case there was further trouble, the docker file was adding additional argument (mainly environmental variables) after my arguments, so the sh command still wasn't last.

Because of this this I had to abandon docker.image().inside and use

`docker run -d -t -v _____ script.sh
 docker exec containername {sh command}`

to start the container and run other commands inside it.